# Pure css method of locking bottom edge of div to viewport

Tags: css

I have two container `div`s that need their bottom edges to be locked x pixels from the bottom of the viewport. I need the same result as using position `absolute|fixed` - yet I need to keep them as `position: relative` so that they correctly float and position themselves with the rest of the DOM.

I've only been able to find javascript-based solutions and I'd really prefer something in pure css. Hoping someone knows of a solution I don't.

Needs to support IE7+ if possible.

Comment: Shudders -_- "Needs to support IE7+ if possible."

Comment: Sadly that's the primary browser used by the end user...

Comment: I've been there and it is painful.  Hang in there my friend :)

Comment: Nest your 2 divs inside one div that is positioned absolute/fixed at the bottom. If you have any html it would help.

Comment: Also. Please do some research about positioning so that you have a understanding to how it works. http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: I do know how it works. The problem is that the site is responsive and if I were to use absolute/fixed positioning I'd have constantly adjust the top/left offsets as well for all of the size scenarios. I don't want to trap us into fixed pixel values like that

Answer (score 0):

If you must, IE7.js supports fix positioning.

http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I can't use fixed positioning in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of how you can accomplish what you want to do with the guidelines you set.

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/38WqN/

```
<div id="footer">
   <div class="footer-right">
   </div>
   <div class="footer-left">
   </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#footer {
 background: #666;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
}
.footer-right {
 background: #ccc;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 40%;
 display: inline-block;
}
.footer-left {
 background: #ccc;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 40%;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I am not attempting to bind a fixed footer to the viewport. I'm trying to lock the bottom of a content div so that it "follows" the viewport bottom if the screen is resized.